# Can people be bred for tameness in a similar way to Russian foxes?

Tags: human-genetics, artificial-selection

Russian foxes were [selectively bred for tameness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesticated_red_fox). Can a similar process happen to humans, under the right conditions — say, extreme political pressure to obey ?

Comment: Do you understand how the process works for a fox (or anything else for any other trait, for that matter)? Think about what the prerequisites are and what the process is.

Comment: Cages and a basic test for friendliness. I know this has dark resonances for humans and their history - I'm not advocating it, I'm asking if it is a process that happens already. I should maybe change the question to "Have" instead of "Can".

Comment: If a trait is genetically influenced, has variation, and affects production of progeny, it can be selected on, naturally or artificially. So if there is variation in human tameness with a genetic cause (unlikely to have been studied specifically as 'tameness'), and people who are not tame are killed or otherwise prevented from reproducing, then yes, you would select for tameness. You won't be able to get a rigorous result for the more specific questions your question seems to imply or that you've mentioned in a comment.

Comment: OK so thinking about the selection within societies I suppose we're looking back at the beginning of social stratification and law - favouring obedience and punishing disobedience. Sometimes this is highly ruthless and lethal - the USSR would be one example of this. But the activities of Stalin & co were quite brief. But do the selection processes of dictators select for tameness or aggression ? Dictatorships seem to reward both the aggression (on the government side) and obedience (on the citizenry side) simultaneously. OK good thanks you've prompted me to reconsider on this.

Comment: Harpending [wrote](https://westhunt.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/clarkfrost-domestication) about it.

Comment: define tameness in respect to a human. Less likely to get violent, already is being selected for.

Comment: OK how to define it. Good question. In foxes it is friendliness to another species. That wouldn't count for human-human tameness. It's also submission to authority and control - for the foxes that is to the species which cages it. So I would call human tameness a propensity to obey, be friendly towards, rule makers. The law or ruling class.
I read that Russian foxes become tame in six generations. Call a human generation 25 years, and make a huge assumption (probably not true) that humans adapt as quickly, then that would be about 150 years. Some social systems and religions are much older.

Comment: @JimmyWiddle If you're using your actual name, be careful, for you're getting close to *verboten* ideas. Religion civilizing people is indeed an old phenomenon that seems foreign to moderns. Of course, this implies that if Alice's ancestors and Bob's ancestors spent centuries under different religions, then Alice and Bob may be very, very incompatible. Forcing Alice and Bob to live under the same laws and under the same social norms may be a fool's errand.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but I see what you mean. Yeah that could be a hot potato !
I think the foxes are tame to humans generally, not just Russian humans with a certain language, appearance and smell. Would it be different for humans ? I expect this has been considered already, given the authoritarian political regime under which the fox experiments were started, and maybe the reason it was conducted on the quiet out in the sticks.

Comment: @JimmyWiddle In humans, tameness to humans in general and tameness to humans of the same family / clan / tribe / race would be an interesting distinction. If I recall correctly, Dmitry Belyayev was working at the Institute of Cytology and Genetics in [Akademgorodok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademgorodok) — the Soviet version of Los Alamos.

Comment: @JimmyWiddle You may want to read [this](https://westhunt.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/dan-freedmans-babies).

Comment: Quote from Slavoj Zizek, would seem to imply that the search for human tameness genes is ongoing. "I visited China five years ago I got in a conversation with some big shot from their Academy of Biogenetics. I mean biogenetic department of their Academy of Sciences. And he gave me the program of goals of biogenetics in China. A kind of a programmatic text which pretty much terrified me. It opens up the text with something like the goal of biogenetics in the People’s Republic of China is to regulate the physical and the psychic welfare of Chinese people. My God, what does that mean?"

Comment: @JimmyWiddle Einstein himself had [some naughty thoughts](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2018/jun/12/einsteins-travel-diaries-reveal-shocking-xenophobia).

Answer (score 5):

Setting aside the eugenic implications of what are you suggesting (short answer: yes it is theoretically possible, but no it is practically impossible), a more interesting observation is that evolutionary anthropologists think that humans might have "self-domesticated" during our evolutionary history.

There is a wide literature on this topic, but a [recent paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0185306) summarizes the main ideas and addresses the question from a genomic point of view. Theofanopoulou and coauthors find credible genomic evidence for similar patterns of genetic evolution in humans and other domesticated animals.

[image: Self-domestication]

Comment: Good yes I was wondering about the natural neotony of humans over time. But the eugenics - I was wondering if it already happened unconsciously, for instance through the communist era in Russia and various other times and places where people have been selected by political or religious systems.
As I understand it the foxes showed signs of change in about 10 generations. In human terms that's somewhere around 250 years I think. Whether there is an equivalence between human and fox generations is part of my question, really.

Comment: @kmm What do you mean with _practically impossible_?

Comment: @Marzipanherz From an implementation (practical) perspective, breeding humans will not work. If there is heritable variation, it can be selected on. Actually doing that selection on humans is impossible.

Comment: @kmm I was thinking, whether something like this might have happend (unintentionally) already: Think of an isolated culture (an island, for example) that prevents non-tame people from getting children (_via_ prison or death penalty). If such a culture has been/is stable for enough generations and assuming that tameness in human was heritable....

Comment: @kmm There are practical ways that artificial selection can be done in humans (This is a different question from whether it *should* be done). A country which is a welfare society could, for example, make [IVF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_vitro_fertilisation) with embryo selection free and legal. When some portion of the variation of trait X is understood genetically (such as from GWAS), then you can select directly at the embryo level. For example, a procedure could be that a couple made 10 fertilized eggs, and then you can select the egg that has the highest probability of high/low X.